# Does ILOnly = 0 mean C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, corflags

Does ILOnly=0 when using corflags means the assembly is built using C++/CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is hardly a slam-dunk, there are a great many .NET compatible compilers out there.  Being able to include relocatable machine code in an assembly has many uses.  But yeah, if you know the assembly was built with Microsoft tools then the C++/CLI compiler was the likely source.  The other compilers they supply only generate pure assemblies.

There's one way to narrow it down, have a look-see with ildasm.exe or Reflector.  If you see a class named `<CppImplementationDetails>` then the odds are very close to 100%.